# Using multiple backgrounds in Opera, can I use a gradient and an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button that has a gradient and an icon using css multiple background but cannot seem to get this working in Opera 10.5. The CSS being used is as follows:

```
background: url(../images/mobile-down-icons.png), -o-linear-gradient(top,#fefefe,#e6e6e6);
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x; 
background-position: 96% 7px, 0 0;
```

Can anyone possibly advise me where I might be going wrong with this?

Comment: It does work for me http://jsfiddle.net/WLwvN/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera didn't support CSS gradients until version 11.10, so in the version you're using (10.5), the `background` declaration is parsed as invalid and not applied at all.

Upgrade your Opera browser and it will work.

Browser support for CSS gradients: http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient